# Any alternatives to maintaining two separate structs with different names?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, opaque-types

Say I have an existing C header that defines a struct with a generic name, inside generic.h like this:

```
typedef struct generic_name_s {
    int    count;
} generic_name_t;
```

I'd like to make generic_name_t type available to users of my SDK, but with a specific name instead of the generic one, so I don't pollute the namespace. I cannot simply use:

```
typedef generic_name_t specific_name_t;
```

since that would require including generic.h inside specific.h, and the namespace I'm exporting to only allows exporting headers that conform to the specific naming conventions (i.e. users of my library can only include specific.h and not generic.h).

One option is to maintain two separate copies of the struct, one with the generic and one with the specific name, but that seems error-prone. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I've tried forward-declaring specific_name_t in specific.h:

```
typedef struct generic_name_s specific_name_t;
```

And then in specific.c, I #include "generic.h", which I thought would complete the definition of struct generic_name_s, but when a user of the library uses it (by doing "#include <specific.h>"), they still cannot access the struct members "variable has incomplete type".

Comment: What do you mean by "expose in another namespace"?

Comment: `they still cannot access the struct members` it should have worked. Please post an [MCVE] - post all the exact files that you are using. Most probably there is a circular include, or you copied include guards, or similar.

Comment: If you cannot use only a _pointer_ to the opaque structure, you need to define the structure _with_ its members. How else can a user of your library, who includes your header file, access a member? So your analysis is correct, either you include "generic.h" in "specific.h" or you define the structure yourself. AFAIK you even cannot include "generic.h" and "specific.h" in your library's source to let the compiler check the equality. It will error because of the redefinition.

Comment: Compatible structure types cannot have different names (tags), per C 2018 6.2.7 1. If the public code does not need to access anything inside the structure, just use pointers to it, you can declare it as `typedef struct specific_name_s specific_name_t;` for the public code and `typedef struct specific_name_s generic_name_t;` for the private code, and you can also provide the structure definition only in the private code. If the public code needs to directly access members, you must make the structure definition visible to the public code…

Comment: … Often “accessor” functions are provided that read or write members given a pointer. Then callers to the accessor functions do not need to see the structure definition; they only need the pointer. You should edit the question to be clearer about the requirements. Does the public code need to access members directly? Is it okay if the private code defines the structure with `struct specific_name_s` as long as it also has the `generic_name_t` type alias to use for it?